# Is $Z_3+{\rm AD}$ equiconsistent with $\text{ZFC+AD}^{L(\mathbb{R})}$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, determinacy

Let $Z_2$ and $Z_3$ be second and third order arithmetics respectively.

In $Z_2$'s language, $\text{AD}$ (the axiom of determinacy) and $\text{PD}$ (projective determinacy) are stated the same way (since projective sets are precisely the ones defined by formulas in $Z_2$'s language). But in $Z_3$'s language we can state $\text{AD}$ and $\text{PD}$ separately.

$Z_2+\text{PD}$, $Z_3+\text{PD}$ and in fact $\text{ZFC+PD}$ are all equiconsistent, and weaker than $\text{ZF+AD / ZFC+AD}^{L(\mathbb{R})}$. I was wondering if $Z_3+\text{AD}$ was also equiconsistent with those, or if it has the full consistency strength of $\text{ZF+AD / ZFC+AD}^{L(\mathbb{R})}$ (or falls somewhere inbetween). I would appreciate a reference or a proof sketch.

Comment: How is $Z_3+\mathrm{PD}$ equiconsistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}+\mathrm{PD}$? The latter proves the consistency of the former.

Comment: According to wikipedia $\text{ZFC}+$"there are n Woodin cardinals" for all n is conservative over $Z_2+\text{PD}$ for s.o.a. sentences, so there should be equiconsistency, and I do believe that this extension of ZFC is equiconsistent with ZFC+PD. I remember seeing that result in a paper too.

Comment: Surely you can see how $\mathrm{ZFC}+\mathrm{PD}$ proves that there are set models of $Z_3+\mathrm{PD}$, right?

Comment: Yes but this conflict with results I think I saw so I'm a bit lost now

Comment: I think there's a confusion here between PD, which is a single sentence, and the infinite set of sentences $\{\text{Det}(\mathbold{\Sigma}^1_n):n=1,2,\dots\}$. I could believe equiconsistency for the infinite sets; $Z_3$ plus a particular level of determinacy should give a model of ZFC plus a slightly lower level of determinacy.  But for the single sentences, you definitely don't get equiconsistency.

Comment: An example of a true result along these lines is that $Z_2+\Delta^1_2$-determinacy is equiconsistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}+$"there is a Woodin cardinal". As Andreas suggests, you probably want to clarify whether you actually mean the schematic version of $\mathrm{PD}$.

Comment: @Andrés If ZFC holds and there is a Woodin cardinal $\delta$, doesn't $\Delta^1_2$ determinacy hold in $V[G]$ where $G \subset \text{Col}(\omega,\delta)$ is $V$-generic, giving a set model $(V_\omega, V_{\omega+1}; \mathord{\in})^{V[G]}$ of $Z_2 + \Delta^1_2$ determinacy?

Comment: @Trevor Agh, sorry, that was a horrible typo. I meant to write "$\mathrm{ORD}$ is Woodin". But now I am not even sure this is quite correct; it seems to be open. In the Koellner-Woodin chapter in the Handbook, they state without proof that $Z_3+\Delta^1_2$-determinacy is equiconsistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}_2+$"$\mathrm{ORD}$ is Woodin", where $\mathrm{ZFC}_2$ is second-order $\mathrm{ZFC}$. Actually, that chapter is a good reference for these matters. For instance, they obtain that $Z_2+$ boldface $\Delta^1_2$-determinacy implies the consistency of $\mathrm{ZFC}+$"there is a Woodin cardinal",

Comment: @Trevor As you point out, from models for the latter we can obtain by forcing models of $\mathrm{ZFC}+$ (lightface) $\Delta^1_2$-determinacy. (The gap between the boldface and lightface versions is actually considerable.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reference I know for precisely these matters is the handbook chapter

> [MR2768702](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2768702). Koellner, Peter; Woodin, W. Hugh. *[Large cardinals from determinacy](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-5764-9_24)*. In **Handbook of set theory. Vols. 1, 2, 3**, 1951–2119, Springer, Dordrecht, 2010.

(Particularly, section 7.)

For closely related topics, see also the work of Yong Cheng (and of Cheng and Schindler) on Harrington's principle.

First of all, $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{PD}$ proves the consistency of $Z_3+\mathsf{PD}$, and similarly $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{AD}$ and $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{AD}^{L(\mathbb R)}$ prove the consistency of $Z_3+\mathsf{AD}$: (depending on your precise formulation of second- and third-order arithmetic), $(V_\omega,V_{\omega+1},V_{\omega+2},\in)^{L(\mathbb R)}$ is a model of the latter.

That said, however, (as pointed out by Andreas in a comment) there is a subtlety here in that $\mathsf{PD}$ is a single sentence. If instead we consider the infinite collection of axioms, the $n$th of which states the determinacy of boldface $\Sigma^1_n$-games, we should probably get equiconsistency, perhaps after some minor tweaking of the theories.

Section 7 of the reference above addresses these matters in reasonable detail for $\mathsf{ZFC}+$"there is a Woodin cardinal" and close variants, and $Z_2+$ lightface $\Delta^1_2$-determinacy, and close variants. For instance, from $Z_2+$ boldface $\Delta^1_2$-determinacy, they obtain (something stronger than) the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}+$"There is a Woodin cardinal". Note that the latter theory is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}+$ lightface $\Delta^1_2$-determinacy which, in turn, implies the consistency of $Z_2+$ lightface $\Delta^1_2$-determinacy, so one needs to be careful here. They conjecture that $Z_2+$ lightface $\Delta^1_2$-determinacy is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}+$"$\mathrm{ORD}$ is Woodin". In any case, from these results and the techniques in that chapter (particularly in section 6) one should obtain the equiconsistency results I suggested in the previous paragraph.